# Where's the error in js validation

Tags: javascript

I'm working on form validation right now. Onsubmit is sumbmitting when there are errors. I'm not sure where the problem is. I'm thinking it's around the regex portions of the code, but not sure. Where's the error in this validation script?

```
function test_form()
{

  var userName = document.regForm.userName.value;
  var firstName = document.regForm.firstName.value;
  var lastName = document.regForm.lastName.value;
  var email = document.regForm.email.value;
  var email2 = document.regForm.email2.value;
  var password = document.regForm.password.value;
  var password2 = document.regForm.password2.value;
  var birthDay = document.regForm.birthDay.value;
  var birthMonth = document.regForm.birthMonth.value;
  var birthYear = document.regForm.birthYear.value;
  var tou = document.regForm.tou.checked;

  var regSpec = /!|@|#|\$|%|-|_|&|\*|\(|\)|\+|\[|\]|\{|\}|:|;|'|"|\||\\|,|<|>|\.|\?|\/|\^/;
  var regUser = /!|@|#|\$|%|&|\*|\(|\)|\+|\[|\]|\{|\}|:|;|'|"|\||\\|,|<|>|\.|\?|\/|\^/;

  var error = false;

  // Test all fields for empty and dob format and tou acceptance

 if(userName === "" || firstName === "" || lastName === "" || email === "" || email2 ===    ""     || password === "" || password2 === "" || tou == false || birthDay == "--Day--" ||         birthYear == "--Year--" || birthMonth == "--Month--")
 {

   error = true;

 }

  // Test all fields for applicable special characters

 if(firstName.match(regSpec) || lastName.match(regSpec))
 {

  error = true;

 }


 if(userName.match(regUser) || password.match(regUser) || password2.match(regUser))
 {

  error = true;

 }

 // Test emails for format and match

 if(email.indexOf("@") == -1 || email.indexOf(".") == -1 || email2.indexOf("@") == -1 ||      email2.indexOf(".") == -1)
  {

   error = true;

  }

 // Test passwords for match

 if(password != password2)
 {

  error = true;

 }

  // test email for match

 if(email != email2)
 {

  error = true;

 }

 // Send

 return error;


}
```

Comment: How are you using this function. To stop the submit of the form you must `return false`. If this function is used as the onsubmit handler then if there is an error the function returns true, which will mean the form will submit

Comment: Save your time and efforts, and just use well-tested and stable jquery validation plugin

Comment: And also, keep in mind, that in order to pass validation, a user might simply disable JavaScript in his browser. You always have to validate data on server side!

Answer (score 0):

How are you using this function. To stop the submit of the form you must return false. If this function is used as the onsubmit handler then if there is an error the function returns true, which will mean the form will submit –  OJay 16 mins ago

This commenter was right. I changed my boolean to noError and made sure the errors set this to false. Works great now. Just need to do some php validation too :) Thanks.